# Getting vslam_tutorial.bag working on Fuerte

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, vslam, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The "vslam_tutorial.bag" provided in this tutorial (http://www.ros.org/wiki/vslam_system/Tutorials/RunningVslamOnStereoData) is in Cturtle format. There is a fix suggested (migrating the bag forward) but it doesn't seem to fix it for Fuerte (my version of ROS). Could anyone provide a .bag file I can use in VSLAM running in Fuerte? Or is there a way of migrating the .bag file forward such that it is compatible with Fuerte?

Here is the error message:

yglee@yglee-VirtualBox:~/ros_workspace/VSLAMDIR/vslam_system$ rosbag play --clock ../vslam_tutorial.bag
[ INFO] [1341638342.853215782]: Opening ../vslam_tutorial.bag

Waiting 0.2 seconds after advertising topics... done.

Hit space to toggle paused, or 's' to step.

"[ERROR] [1341638343.740372455]: Client [/wide_stereo/stereo_vslam_node] wants topic /wide_stereo/left/camera_info to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/c9a58c1b0b154e0e6da7578cb991d214], but our version has [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/1b5cf7f984c229b6141ceb3a955aa18f]. Dropping connection.
[ERROR] [1341638343.741226976]: Client [/wide_stereo/stereo_vslam_node] wants topic /wide_stereo/right/camera_info to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/c9a58c1b0b154e0e6da7578cb991d214], but our version has [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo/1b5cf7f984c229b6141ceb3a955aa18f]. Dropping connection."

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38319/getting-vslam_tutorial.bag-working-on-fuerte/) by [yglee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2776/yglee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yglee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2776/yglee/) on 2012-07-10**:
HI Willow Garage, Could one of you ( VSLAM team) please provide example .bag files for the vslam on Fuerte? Thanks.

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-07-10**:
Note the giant red warning box on the VSLAM wikipage; this software is no longer supported in any form. (For example, there hasn't been anything like a "vslam team" in several years).

**Comment by [yglee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2776/yglee/) on 2012-07-10**:
Ah I see. Then to the general audience: did anyone get VSLAM working on Fuerte? If so, is there an example data file (.bag) you can share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The CameraInfo message changed a while back. You can run rosbag fix to upgrade the message to the current version. I have used it before to convert old bag files to Diamondback and Electric.

---

Originally posted by [Hordur](https://answers.ros.org/users/418/hordur/) with karma: 544 on 2012-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yglee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2776/yglee/) on 2012-07-10**:
It doesn't work for Fuerte but thanks for the suggestion (let me know if you got it working for Fuerte).